# Is is possible to Create an Alias of a Form Control by Changing the name property

Tags: c#, wpf, reference, controls, alias

Suppose I have a ComboBox with name, **myComboBox**.

Now, if I declare another ComboBox reference, say:

```
ComboBox curBox=new ComboBox();
curBox.Name = curCombo; // curCombo is a string whose value is myComboBox.
```

Will **curBox** then be an alias  for, that is directly refer to **myComboBox**.

Comment: Sounds like you might want to consider the proxy pattern > http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name property of a WPF control is just used to fill the name attribute in your XAML markup. It should be unique as it provides a (high-level) reference to your control (you can find your control by name).

In your example, myComboBox and curBox are two separate instances of a ComboBox, who will simply share the same name. This is not allowed as names should be unique within a Namescope. [See here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms746659.aspx) for more on this subject.

Comment: Actually I was able to assign it, but what would be the behavior?

Comment: @Gunner: In what scenario? The two ComboBoxes only have the name in common. Or more accurately, their names reference the same string. What behavior do you expect to be influenced?

Answer (score 1):

Rewinder is right, just want to add:
setting `curBox.Name` in code does not automatically add this control to the current Namescope. So, setting it should not be a problem. For adding it to the namescope you would use [RegisterName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.namescope.registername.aspx) which will throw an `ArgumentException` if the "name provided would result in a duplicate name registration".

Comment: Actually, you need to call RegisterName(string name, Object scopedElement) as well. This will raise an exception on duplicate names.

Comment: @Rewinder oh, my bad. That was what I actually wanted to put in there. I even wondered why the msdn didn't say anything about an exception for duplicate names, but didn't get I was in the wrong method. Thanks buddy, off to change...